# Dato-Graphlab Check if Edge exists

Tags: python, networkx, graphlab

I've just installed Graphlab and am trying to convert NetworkX code to Graphlab.  I'm having trouble finding in the Graphlab documentation the NetworkX equivalent of `G.has_edge()`.  If a similar function does not exist, how would one check if an Graphlab Edge already exists in the Graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SGraph.get_edges` method can be used to check if a particular edge exists. In my example below I create a "chain" graph where vertices with consecutive integers are connected by an edge.

```
>>> import graphlab
>>> g = graphlab.SGraph().add_edges(
        [graphlab.Edge(i, i+1) for i in range(4)])

# Edge does exist.
>>> test1 = g.get_edges(src_ids=[0], dst_ids=[1])
>>> test1.num_rows()
1

# Edge does *not* exist.
>>> test2 = g.get_edges(src_ids=[0], dst_ids=[2])
>>> test2.num_rows()
0
```

Here's the link to the API docs for `get_edges`: https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SGraph.get_edges.html